# How to include third party JS in angular 2+ conditionally (environment based)

Tags: angular

How to include third party JS in angular 2+ conditionally (environment based).

I need to include adobe analytics for which I need to include the script.

script included should be conditional for staging and production environment as URL/ codes are different for tracking.

any suggestion/ help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is going to be off my mind. add the necessary scripts inside a folder and segregate them in files (I mean `export` them) based on environments, eg: `js/ex-scripts.js`, `js/ex-scripts.prod.js`. Then add a single entry under `scripts` **angular.json** as `"scripts": [...something here, src/js/ex-scripts.js']`. Now, look for `fileReplacements` in `configurations` and then replace files based on env. Do it for dev, prod, test etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new DOM element `script` in `head` tag of document with code below :

```
let node = document.createElement('script');
node.src = ...;
node.type = 'text/javascript';
node.charset = 'utf-8';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
```

Pay attention, to execute this code only once. (inside a single instance service for example). 
And also it's a best practice to check if `document` exists.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScriptService {
  constructor() {
    // call once, because of 'providedIn: root' => singleton instance
    if (document && environment.production) {
      // browser platform
      let node = document.createElement('script');
      node.src = 'https://....analytics.js';
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.charset = 'utf-8';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, inject singleton service inside your component :

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(
    private scriptService: ScriptService
  ) { }
}
```

When your component will be instantiated for the first time, `ScriptService` will be instantiated also, but only once, and your `script` element will be added to `document` only if environment is production.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Angular CLI v 6 and above`, you can use the configuration section in `angular.json`to load and replace different files for different environments

For your purpose, create two similar index files (as `src/index.html`) and name them `src/index.prod.html` and `src/index.staging.html`

Add **`src/index.prod.html`**

```
<html>
    <head>
      ...
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//analytics.prod.js"></script>
      ...
   </head>
   ...
</html>
```

Add **`src/index.staging.html`**

```
<html>
    <head>
      ...
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//analytics.staging.js"></script>
      ...
   </head>
   ...
</html>
```

Update **angular.json**

```
...

"configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/index.html",
                  "with": "src/index.prod.html"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/index.html",
                  "with": "src/index.staging.html"
                }
              ]
            },
...
```

Comment: this wont work since angular version 9. html replacements are not allowed anymore